# unsafe структура с фиксированным массивом структур

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe

Пробую перенести одну из структур с из `DXGI`, но столкнулся с проблемой.

Определение структуры

```
typedef struct DXGI_GAMMA_CONTROL {
  DXGI_RGB Scale;
  DXGI_RGB Offset;
  DXGI_RGB GammaCurve[1025];
} DXGI_GAMMA_CONTROL, *LPDXGI_GAMMA_CONTROL;
```

Хорошо, пробую перенести:

Структура `DxgiRbg`:

```
/// <summary>
///     Represents an RGB color.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DxgiRgb
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     A value representing the color of the red component. The range of this value is between 0 and 1.
    /// </summary>
    public float Red;

    /// <summary>
    ///     A value representing the color of the green component. The range of this value is between 0 and 1.
    /// </summary>
    public float Green;

    /// <summary>
    ///     A value representing the color of the blue component. The range of this value is between 0 and 1.
    /// </summary>
    public float Blue;
}
```

Проблемная структура:

```
/// <summary>
///     Controls the settings of a gamma curve.
/// </summary>
public struct DxgiGammaControl
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     A <see cref="DxgiRgb" /> structure with scalar values that are applied to rgb values before being sent to the gamma
    ///     look up table.
    /// </summary>
    public DxgiRgb Scale;

    /// <summary>
    ///     A <see cref="DxgiRgb" /> structure with offset values that are applied to the rgb values before being sent to the
    ///     gamma look up table.
    /// </summary>
    public DxgiRgb Offset;

    /// <summary>
    ///     An array of <see cref="DxgiRgb" /> structures that control the points of a gamma curve.
    /// </summary>
    private unsafe fixed DxgiRgb GammaCurve[1025];
}
```

Проблема с определением поля

```
private unsafe fixed DxgiRgb GammaCurve[1025];
```

т.к. массивы фиксированной длины могут быть только из стандартных типов `int`, `short`, `byte` и т.д.

Как перенести такой массив кроме как выделением общего кол-ва байт под весь массив фиксированным полем?

```
fixed byte gammaCureve[Size_All_1025_Structs];
```

Ведь тут будут накладные расходы времени на вычисление позиции структур на основе их размеров и индекса который был запрошен.

Или завести стурктуру с общим объемом требуемой памяти и читать дынные из нее?

---

**UPD:**

Одно из придуманных  мной извращений выглядит так:

Структура помощник:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 12300)]
internal unsafe struct GammaCurveStructArrayHelper
{
    internal DxgiRgb ReadById(int index)
    {
        fixed (GammaCurveStructArrayHelper* fixedThisPtr = &this)
        {
            IntPtr startData = new IntPtr(fixedThisPtr);
            return Marshal.PtrToStructure<DxgiRgb>(IntPtr.Add(startData,
                index * HelperDataGet.SizeStruct));
        }
    }

    internal void ReadAllArrayData(out DxgiRgb[] arrayDxgiRgb)
    {
        arrayDxgiRgb = new DxgiRgb[1025];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1025; i++) ReadOutWithId(i, out arrayDxgiRgb[i]);
    }

    internal void ReadOutWithId(int index, out DxgiRgb dxgiRgb)
    {
        fixed (GammaCurveStructArrayHelper* fixedThisPtr = &this)
        {
            IntPtr startData = new IntPtr(fixedThisPtr);
            dxgiRgb = Marshal.PtrToStructure<DxgiRgb>(IntPtr.Add(startData,
                index * HelperDataGet.SizeStruct));
        }
    }

    internal void WriteDataById(int index, DxgiRgb dxgiRgb)
    {
        fixed (GammaCurveStructArrayHelper* fixedThisPtr = &this)
        {
            IntPtr writeIdPtr = IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(fixedThisPtr), index * HelperDataGet.SizeStruct);
            IntPtr rgbPtr = new IntPtr(&dxgiRgb);
            Marshal.Copy(rgbPtr, new[] {writeIdPtr}, 0, HelperDataGet.SizeStruct);
        }
    }

    internal void WriteDataArray(DxgiRgb[] array)
    {
        if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));

        if (array.Length < 1025 || array.Length > 1025)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Writable array cannot be greater than 1025 element and less than 1025 elements!",
                nameof(array));

        for (int i = 0; i < 1025; i++) WriteDataById(i, array[i]);
    }
}

internal struct HelperDataGet
{
    internal const int SizeStruct = 12;
}
```

И реализация чтения/записи:

```
/// <summary>
///     Controls the settings of a gamma curve.
/// </summary>
public struct DxgiGammaControl
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     A <see cref="DxgiRgb" /> structure with scalar values that are applied to rgb values before being sent to the gamma
    ///     look up table.
    /// </summary>
    public DxgiRgb Scale;

    /// <summary>
    ///     A <see cref="DxgiRgb" /> structure with offset values that are applied to the rgb values before being sent to the
    ///     gamma look up table.
    /// </summary>
    public DxgiRgb Offset;

#pragma warning disable 649
    private GammaCurveStructArrayHelper _helper;
#pragma warning restore 649

    /// <summary>
    ///     An array of <see cref="DxgiRgb"/> structures that control the points of a gamma curve.
    /// </summary>
    public DxgiRgb[] GammaCurve
    {
        get
        {
            _helper.ReadAllArrayData(out DxgiRgb[] arrayData);
            return arrayData;
        }

        set => _helper.WriteDataArray(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DxgiGammaControl {
    public DxgiRgb Scale;
    public DxgiRgb Offset;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1025)]
    public DxgiRgb[] GammaCurve;
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays#arrays-within-structures

Comment: Похоже что данный аттрибут решит еще несколько моих проблем =)